# (PHP) Passing multiple parameters within shell_exec() to bash script

Tags: php, bash, email, ansible, shell-exec

I'm trying to send an email through Ansible via PHP.

My PHP script contains the following code:

```
$dest = "myemail@company.com";
$oggetto = "Test subject";
$corpo = "Test email body";
shell_exec("//opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/cugo/runyaml.sh '$dest' '$oggetto' '$corpo'");
```

runyaml.sh contains:

```
ansible-playbook /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/cugo/mailSender.yml --extra-vars "destinatari=$dest oggetto=$oggetto corpo=$corpo"
```

while mailSender.yml contains:

```
-
  name: emailsender
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  -
    name: sendmail
    mail:
      host: xxx
      port: 25
      username: xxx
      password: xxx
      to: "{{ destinatari }}"
      from: automation@company.com
      subject: "{{ oggetto }}"
      body: "{{ corpo }}"
      subtype: html
```

Unfortunately the mail is not sent, while if I manually type "to, subject, body" inside "mailSender.yml", then everything works. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in the way I pass the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dots "." to concatenate the variables

```
shell_exec("//opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/cugo/runyaml.sh '" . $dest."' '".$oggetto."' '".$corpo."'");
```

You can also try to print the received parameters to verify if they are passing correctly

Comment: Thanks but still not working (tried with your edited answer)

Comment: If can be helpful, ansible-playbook /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/cugo/mailSender.yml --extra-vars "destinatari='mymail@company.com' oggetto='qwerty' corpo='wsda'" works perfectly

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: Tried but still nothing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).